# Pydrake: Accessing extra SNOPT solver outputs (iter)

Tags: drake

According to the [SNOPT docs](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/guides/sndoc7.pdf) (page 57), one of the outputs of SNOPT upon exit is `iter`, the number of major iterations performed. I was wondering if there is any way to access this output when using `SnoptSolver` in pydrake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iter` is available in SNOPT's `npOpt` interface,unfortunately we use `snoptA` interface (chapter 3 of SNOPT doc https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/guides/sndoc7.pdf) in Drake's wrapper class `SnoptSolver`, I don't think this `snoptA` interface returns `iter` on exit.

If you want to know the number of iterations, you could print the snopt progress. One example to do that is

```py
# Print out the progress to my_output.txt
prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver.solver_id(), "Print file", "my_output.txt")
result = snopt_solver.Solve(prog)
```

In `my_output.txt` you will see the number of iterations.